# How to ListContourPlot a functional eigenvalue spectrum?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

We have a (Hermitian) matrix of some finite dimension (n) whose elements are functions of real variables x and y. We wish to plot contours of the spectrum (level sets of the n real eigenvalues) at chosen values.

**Here's a simple solution using `ContourPlot`:**

```
matrix = Table[3 i x + j y, {i, 5}, {j, 5}]; 
ContourPlot[Sort@Re@Eigenvalues[matrix], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},Contours->{0.3, 1.7}] /. _Polygon -> Sequence[]
```

To be honest, I am not quite sure *why* this does work--although it does--as the syntax does not appear to follow the documentation for `ContourPlot` precisely. Here, the argument of `ContourPlot` is an 5-dimensional list of eigenvalues, presumably sampled at some point in the x-y domain. Using `PlotPoints` seems to increase the grain size in the domain mesh.

Also, obviously in this example, the eigenvalues have analytic closed-form expressions as functions of x and y, but in my general problem, that is not possible. However, this `ContourPlot` method has worked in the past nonetheless.

**However, I wish to discretize this process manually using `ListContourPlot`**. I hope to gain the ability to manually control the domain and mesh size and also make the contour plotting significantly faster (the `ContourPlot` version above is quite slow in the real problem).

I am really struggling with the syntax of `ListContourPlot`, though. Note that the matrix we examine is given. I need to

1. Construct a domain (presumably a `List` of `List`s like {0.234,-0.412}, etc., a list of {x,y} points in the domain).
2. Numerically evaluate the `Eigenvalues` of the matrix at every point in the domain, and store these results (n-dimensional lists) somehow.
3. Compile the many eigenvalue lists (one at every site in the discrete domain) into a complex array which fits the syntax for `ListContourPlot`
4. Perform the `ListContourPlot` and isolated chosen level sets using the `Contours` option.

**The start of a weak working example**

```
matrix = Table[3 i x + j y, {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
domain = Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, 0.5}, {y, -1, 1, 0.5}];
II = Dimensions[domain][[1]];
JJ = Dimensions[domain][[2]];
array = domain;
Do[array[[i, j]] = {array[[i, j, 1]], array[[i, j, 2]], 
Sort@Re@Eigenvalues[
  ReplaceAll[
   matrix, {x -> domain[[i, j, 1]], 
    y -> domain[[i, j, 2]]}]]}, {i, 1, II}, {j, 1, JJ}]
```

This is my best effort so far. However, I'm certain that someone can help me find much more elegant solutions to many of these steps.

1. I build a `domain` using Table, but this could definitely be improved. For example, suppose I wished to use all points (x,y) on a square lattice with some density which lie within a `Polygon` instead of a simple rectangle?
2. This point is at least accomplished in `array`, which contains a matrix of lists {x,y,{eigenvalues}}
3. However, this part is a huge failure. The syntax is not commensurable with ListContourPlot in the slightest, so we've really accomplished little.

Please help!

Comment: does a contour represent the locus where "any" eigenvalue is equal to some specified value?  As noted your first example is not a documented usage and its not really clear what its doing.

Comment: Yes, the contours should represent level sets of any eigenvalue in the spectrum. So the contour at value 1.35 should represent the set (disjoint union of 1-dimensional closed curves) of all points in the x,y plane where there is an eigenvalue with value 1.35.

Answer (score 1):

here is one approach:  create a separate plot for each contour and combine.

```
matrix = Table[3 i x + j y, {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
domain = Table[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2, 0.05}, {y, -2, 2, 0.05}]; 
cp[lambda_, color_] := ListContourPlot[Flatten[Map[ Append[#,
      Quiet[First@MinimalBy[
         Cases[
           Chop@Eigenvalues[
             matrix /. { x -> #[[1]] , y -> #[[2]]  } ], _Real]
          - lambda , 
         Abs, 1]]] & , domain, {2}], 1], Contours -> {0},
  ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> color]
contours = Range[-5, 5];
cf = ColorData["DarkRainbow"];
Show[Table[ 
  cp[contours[[i]], cf[i/Length@contours]], {i, Length@contours}]]
```

[image]

note this is based on the real eigenvalues, not the real parts of all the eigenvalues. You can just stick a `Re` in there if that's what you really want.

for reference here is the `ContourPlot` version with the same contours.
(this takes a long time with `PlotPoints->100`)

```
matrix = Table[3 i x + j y, {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
ContourPlot[
  Sort@Cases[Chop@Eigenvalues[matrix], _Real], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
   Contours -> Range[-5, 5], PlotPoints -> 100] /. _Polygon -> 
  Sequence[]
```

[image]

obviously similar. Not sure why my version has that extra set of bands.

Comment: Since the OP claims his matrix is Hermitian, the eigenvalues ought to be always real.

Comment: @J.M. not so for this example. Actually those spurious bands are in the region where there are complex eigenvalues.  I guess not worth worrying about since its a toy example.

Comment: Unfortunately, your discrete version above gives errors (despite the `Quiet`) and does not work for me. Your continuous code below works, (but is quite slow, as you mentioned). edit: This is because `MinimalBy` was added in *mma* version 10, but I am using only version 9.0

Comment: In the real problem, all of the matrices I care about are indeed Hermitian. I should have given a Hermitian toy example, sorry. However, numerical machine error will often give eigenvalues with imaginary parts on the order of 10^(-17), etc., so I remove these confusions typically by just using a `Re`.